# How do I convert an interface{} value to a statically typed value using a function in golang?

Tags: go

In standard library, I can do JSON conversion to a typed object using pointer. The question now is, how do I create a similar method like `json.Marshal` to convert an `v interface{}` to typed object? Do I need to use `reflect` in doing this?

Please see below code snippets, and I am looking for somebody who could fill in the `TODO` in the `home` package. Thank you.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "./home"
)

type Dog struct {
    Name         string
    FavoriteGame string
}

func (dog Dog) Greet() {
    dog.Bark()
}

func (dog Dog) Bark() {
    if len(dog.Name) == 0 {
        panic("This dog has no name!")
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s < Wo! Wo! %s!\n", dog.Name, dog.FavoriteGame)
}

type Cat struct {
    Name         string
    FavoriteMeat string
}

func (cat Cat) Greet() {
    cat.Purr()
}

func (cat Cat) Purr() {
    if len(cat.Name) == 0 {
        panic("This cat has no name!")
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s < purrrrrrr... %s...\n", cat.Name, cat.FavoriteMeat)
}

func main() {
    // JSON decoder works here
    j := []byte(`{"Name": "Jack", "FavoriteGame": "Swim"}`)
    var jack Dog
    json.Unmarshal(j, &jack)
    jack.Bark()

    // Similarly, how do I implement `home` to make the below work?
    dogHome := home.Home{Dog{Name: "Bullet", FavoriteGame: "Catch The Ball"}}
    var bullet Dog
    dogHome.GetPet(&bullet)
    bullet.Bark()

    catHome := home.Home{Cat{Name: "Ball", FavoriteMeat: "Tuna"}}
    var ball Cat
    catHome.GetPet(&ball)
    ball.Purr()
}
```

The other package:

```
package home

type Pet interface {
    Greet()
}

type Home struct {
    Pet Pet
}

func (h Home) GetPet(v interface{}) {
    // TODO: What should I do here?
    v = h.Pet
}
```

Comment: Yes, you need `reflect`. Without anymore details about your goal, that's as specific an answer as you'll get.

Comment: Thank you Tim. Let me add some details here.

Comment: @TimCooper: I have added  the details. Would you take a look please?

Comment: Avoid reflection whenever possible. You could use a two valued [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) such as `bullet, ok := dogHome.Pet.(Dog)` or a [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches).

Comment: @DaveC: Why should we avoid reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [reflect](https://godoc.org/reflect) package:

```
func (h Home) GetPet(v interface{}) {
    reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(h.Pet))
}
```

The expression `reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem()` is the reflect value for what the argument points to.  The Set method sets that value.

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/AHLzABgMzcj)

A better approach is to use type assertions directly in the application:

```
dogHome := Home{Dog{Name: "Bullet", FavoriteGame: "Catch The Ball"}}
bullet := dogHome.Pet.(Dog)
bullet.Bark()

catHome := Home{Cat{Name: "Ball", FavoriteMeat: "Tuna"}}
ball := catHome.Pet.(Cat)
ball.Purr()
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/J3Z5Buk9pQj)

Comment: Thank you. I have been wandering the entire morning for this.

Comment: Thanks for the second approach. May I know why it is a better approach please?

Comment: @hllau Built-in language features are preferred over library functions.  Perhaps there's an unstated requirement that rules out the use of the reflect package, but the problem as stated in the question can be solved using type assertions.